# How do I hide all the extra files from a published windows forms project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to publish to my desktop a little app I've been working on in visual studio but when I publish it there are also some other files like the .dll or the .pdb files without which the app does not run and I don't want those cluttering my desktop so can I somehow integrate them in the app itself or put them in a different folder?

I've tried looking for answers on youtube but all the videos are from like 2015 so they don't work and all the tutorials made by Microsoft are either not what I'm looking for or too technical for a beginner cs student to know if they are or to follow along.

Comment: If you select "Releases" in the Solutions Configuration Drop Down, the debug files will not be created.

Comment: Hi, what you probably want to do is to publish to some location, and create a shortcut on your desktop, pointing at the exe.

Comment: @Andrei Catrinescu，I have made an answer about it. Do you have time to check it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want not to publish the `.pdb` file ,you just need to add this in the `app.config` file:

```
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>None</DebugType>
```

Since you are a c# student, I think what you need to do is just to `right-click` the `.exe` file after publishing to create a `desktop shortcut`:

[image]

Or add the following statement in the [`post-build event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022):

```
xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
```

$(TargetPath):The absolute path name of the primary output file for the build (defined as drive + path + base name + file extension)

The following path is the path you specified, and you can change it according to your needs.